# Adding user for a SQL Server 2008 database - no password field?

Tags: sql-server

I have an ASP.NET app that needs to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database. When I try add the user (specified in a connection string within the app) using Management Studio it doesn't ask for a password for that user - why is this?

(so all i keep getting when i run the app is "Login failed for user 'user'.")

Answer (score 6):

Because users don't have passswords in SQL Server. Only **logins** have passwords. You need to create first a login (a server principal), see [How to: Create a SQL Server Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) and then create a corresponding user in the database (a database principal), see [How to: Create a Database User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx).

To understand the difference between logins and users read [Identity and Access Control (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510418.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Could either be using windows authentication so it doesn't need a password as they are authenticated by the OS/domain.

If it is using SQL Authentication (which requires a username and password). Add the user in the server > security > logins section then give that user access to the database required.

Does that help?